# What to do about my 4-year-old granddaughter who doesn't like to sleep?

Tags: pre-schooler, sleep

My 4-year-old granddaughter lives with me and I have her a lot of the time because my daughter works nights at her job. From the time she was born she didn't really sleep much. She didn't even take an hour nap. And until this day the child just doesn't want to sleep.

I religiously give her a bath for 6:30 and start the process of winding her down. I have her in bed for 8:30 every night. Because my daughter and family members rocked her in a rocking chair and/or layed with her in her bed since birth, it's the only way she'll go to sleep. Friday and sometimes Saturday night I'll keep her up until maybe 10 - 10:30 hoping that she'll sleep late the next day. Well that "never" happens.

I'm really desperate for suggestions. What can I do to make her sleep?

Comment: Do you think that she gets enough sleep currently? What kinds of signs of sleepiness or sleeplessness do you see during the day?  Does she take a nap?  When does she wake up?  And, does she wake up on her own, or do you need to wake her up?

Comment: My niece used to do that to her mother.  It was a power-thing.  When the hunger for power over adults was addressed it strongly mitigated the 1am bedtime target.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not willing to do the same thing her mama and daddy did, you're going to have to retrain her..and that might take some time.  Personally, I say, let her stay up till she falls over.  She's not going to school.  How late can *you* stay up--because we would want the baby supervised of course.  But, if you can stay up later---let her stay up till she falls out.

Answer (score 0):

I had one kid that I could put in bed at any time and he would wake up 11-12 hours later.

The rest... ummm no.

For a 4 year-old I wouldn't expect her to get up late.  They only do that if you need to get to work early.  It is really easy.  Set a bed time.  Let's say 9:00PM.  Put some pillow toys in bed with here - some flashlight type toys.

She will play with the toys until she falls asleep.  She will then get more and more bored with the toys and fall asleep easier each night on her own.  Proven method I used on my other 3.  (this does not mean she gets Barbie or cars or trains and normal toys in bed)